# Keep getting "No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers."

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, printing, dymo

I've been trying to print label files through my web application and integrated "PreviewAndPrintLabel.js" in source code. Though my system does not physically(as hardware) has DYMO printer but I've downloaded DYMO SDK, installed it and added DYMO printer to "Devices and printers" into control panel. Even after adding printer in control panel I'm getting the same error that I was getting before sdk installation. I'm not sure what am I missing here? Had anyone faced such issue in past, it would be great if he/she could help me out to resolve this? I've been struggling out from last 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. After downloading the [SDK](http://www.dymo.com/en-US/online-support/online-support-sdk) and opening the examples in `DYMO Label v.8 SDK/DYMO Label Framework/Samples/JavaScript/Samples/*` all examples where broken, telling me that framework and printer were not installed.

However some examples from this [blog](http://developers.dymo.com/2016/11/29/sample-samples-samples/) worked (`Check environment`, `Print me that label` and `QR Code`) worked for me.

If they don't work for you, you may want to make sure that you have installed the Web Service when you installed the DYMO Label Software

[image]

for more details see this [blog post](http://developers.dymo.com/2016/08/08/dymo-label-web-service-faq/)

Answer (score -1):

You can test your installation with this environment check sample.

```
<div class="content">
   <button id="checkButton">Check</button>

   <div id='output'>
   </div>
</div>



checkButton.onclick = function()
    {
        try
        {
            //clearOutput();
            var result = dymo.label.framework.checkEnvironment();
            outputLine(" ");
            outputLine("isBrowserSupported: " + result.isBrowserSupported);
            outputLine("isFrameworkInstalled: " + result.isFrameworkInstalled);
            if(dymo.label.framework.init){
                outputLine("isWebServicePresent: " + result.isWebServicePresent);
            }
            outputLine("errorDetails: " + result.errorDetails);
        }
        catch(e)
        {
            alert(e.message || e);
        }
    }
```

[DYMO Label Framework JavaScript Library Samples: Check Environment](http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/samples/js/CheckEnvironment/CheckEnvironment.html)

Hopefully you will find actual problem with this sample.

Comment: please post your own answer and then reference.